# Loop over all combinations of adding 1 to the elements of an array of integers

Tags: c++, arrays

**Background:** I need to do a computation on "half" of a Moore neighborhood in `N` dimensions.

**Problem:** Given an array `a` of `N` integers, how can I loop over all possible arrays constructed from `a` by adding `1` to any number of elements of `a` and apply a function `f` to these arrays?

**Code structure & example:**

```
#include <array>

template<int N>
void f(std::array<int, N> a) {
    // client code
}

template<int N>
void loop(std::array<int, N> a) {
    // for ( auto b: {arrays constructed from a} ) {
    //     f(b);
    // }
}

int main() {
    std::array<int, 2> a = {0, 1};
    return 0;
}
```

In above code example, I want to have the following function calls within `loop`: `f({0,1}), f({1,1}), f({0,2}), f({1,2})`

Comment: What's the maximum value of `N`?

Comment: Usually `N=2` or `N=3`, but a solution for arbitrary `N` would be interesting, still.

Comment: For N up to 64 you can make this very easily by just counting up from 0 to 2^64 - 1 using `uint64_t` and using the i-th bit of the counter to decide whether to add 1 or not to the number in the i-th position of `a`. I doubt that N > 64 makes any sense as the runtime of the program is exponential with respect to N, so even with N in the neighborhood of 40 you are already really stretching it in terms of runtime. Above 64 you can use a bitset, but still, the program is probably never going to finish in time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an array which go from `{0, 0, .., 0}` to `{1, 1, .., 1}`:

```
template <std::size_t N>
bool increase(std::array<int, N>& a)
{
    for (auto rit = a.rbegin(); rit != a.rend(); ++rit) {
        *rit = !*rit;
        if (*rit == 1) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false; // v contains only 0 values now.
}
```

then add iterate and add it to your initial array:

```
const std::array<int, 2> a{2, 1};
std::array<int, 2> offset{};

do {
    f(sum(a, offset));
} while (increase(offset));
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Kq3q7dhK9)

Whole code of Demo:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template <std::size_t N>
bool increase(std::array<int, N>& a)
{
    for (auto rit = a.rbegin(); rit != a.rend(); ++rit) {
        *rit = !*rit;
        if (*rit == 1) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false; // v contains only 0 values now.
}

template <std::size_t N>
std::array<int, N> sum(const std::array<int, N>& lhs, const std::array<int, N>& rhs)
{
    std::array<int, N> res;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != N; ++i) {
        res[i] = lhs[i] + rhs[i];
    }

    return res;
}

template <std::size_t N>
void f(const std::array<int, N>& a)
{
    for (auto e : a) {
        std::cout << e << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    const std::array<int, 2> a{2, 1};
    std::array<int, 2> offset{};

    do {
        f(sum(a, offset));
    } while (increase(offset));
}
```

Comment: Very clever solution! Would you mind putting the linked code in the answer as well for preservation?

Answer (score 1):

The way to enumerate all resulting arrays is a bitset of size `N`. For example with `N = 3` the value `0b001` refers to the array with `1` added to the last element.

Once you know how to enumerate all the results you just have to loop from `0` till `2^N`.

If possible I would not actually construct all the resulting arrays, but rather wrap the input array (or a reference to it) and the bitset that can be incremented to avoid unnecessary copying:

```
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

template <size_t size>
struct add_one_array {
    std::array<int,size>& data;
    unsigned counter = 0;

    void next() { ++ counter; }

    struct proxy {
        std::array<int,size>& data;
        std::bitset<size> offset;
        int operator[](size_t index) {
            return data[index] + offset.test(index);
        }
    };
    proxy get() {
        return { data, {counter}};
    }
};

int main() {
    std::array<int,3> arr{2,0};
    add_one_array<3> aoa{arr};
    for (int i=0;i<8;++i,aoa.next()){
        auto p = aoa.get();
        for (size_t i=0;i<3;++i) std::cout << p[i] << " ";
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jKhen1MGs)

```
2 0 0 
3 0 0 
2 1 0 
3 1 0 
2 0 1 
3 0 1 
2 1 1 
3 1 1
```

Take this with a grain of salt. I only used `std::bitset` for the sake of a simple illustration. Iteration requires to call `next()` which isnt nice, but a full blown iteration with custom iterators would have been less readable. Moreover the hardcoded `3` in several places is not nice, but it should be straightforward to remove those magic numbers. Last but not least, as mentioned in a comment, `unsigned counter = 0;` limits the range of `N` where this approach works.